# Class loaders and Service Loader. Which class loader is used?

Tags: java, classloader, serviceloader

I am working on writing an extensible application.

Reading the documentation about the [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) utility class, I was not able to understand the following sentence:

> The provider must be accessible from the same class loader that was initially queried to locate the configuration file; note that this is not necessarily the class loader from which the file was actually loaded.

Could anyone explain to me what does it mean?

How could I determine which class loader it is used to locate the configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could anyone explain to me what does it mean?

I think it is referring to the fact that `ClassLoaders` can and do perform delegation.  If I perform, say,

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/services/org/my/Service");
```

to find the configuration file, then it may be that the `ClassLoader` for `MyClass` delegates to a parent `ClassLoader`, and maybe that one to its parent, etc. so that it is not the `ClassLoader` I queried (`MyClass.class.getClassLoader()`) that actually loads the config file.

In that case, the specification says that no matter which `ClassLoader` *actually* locates the config file, the service classes it names must be accessible from `MyClass.class.getClassLoader()`.  I take "accessible" here not to preclude its own delegation.

In practice, these provisions are probably more remarkable for `ClassLoader` implementations that follow more interesting strategies than simple delegation up a chain of ClassLoaders, as may be found in JavaEE containers, for example.

> How could I determine which class loader it is used to locate the configuration file?

Generally speaking, you probably do not need to do so.  I would recommend as a best strategy that you ensure that the service classes named by any given service configuration file are all accessible via (all) the same `ClassLoader`s as the config file itself.  Putting them in the same `jar` should accomplish this, for instance.